# VS Code spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exeENOENT Error

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I am a beginner and I have this Error saying [error: spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe ENOENT]
can anybody fix it?
also, I want to know whether the error is serious or not.

[Error ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdA0H.jpg)

I tried to uninstall the program, and reinstall it but did not work.

Comment: honestly i dont know but maybe if you open vs with admin rights also you should look at https://bobcares.com/blog/error-spawn-npm-enoent-issue-on-windows/#:~:text=ENOENT%20is%20short%20for%20Error,into%20the%20%E2%80%9CENOENT%E2%80%9D%20error!